# PHAssetChangeRequest fails unless original image orientation is landscape left

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdata, phasset, ciimage

My PHAssetChangeRequest fails consistently even if I do not modify the `NSData` at all, and just try to reuse it when writing to `PHContentEditingOutput`'s `renderedContentURL` when the image's orientation is anything other than landscape left (1).

I'll get the native pop-up asking for permission if it's landscape left. However if it's anything else, it fails silently (error code `-1`) and the only way I know it's an orientation issue is by viewing Device logs, where I see:

`assetsd(Photos)[10493] <Notice>: Error: Invalid image orientation`

Here's my code:

```
 [lastImageAsset
      requestContentEditingInputWithOptions:options
                          completionHandler:^(PHContentEditingInput *contentEditingInput, NSDictionary *info) {
       NSURL *imageURL = contentEditingInput.fullSizeImageURL;
       NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];

       PHContentEditingOutput *output = [[PHContentEditingOutput alloc]initWithContentEditingInput:contentEditingInput];
       PHAdjustmentData *adjustmentData = [[PHAdjustmentData alloc]initWithFormatIdentifier:@"Some Identifier" formatVersion:@"1.0" data:[@"Changed Something" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
       [output setAdjustmentData:adjustmentData];
       [imageData writeToURL:output.renderedContentURL atomically:YES];

       [[PHPhotoLibrary sharedPhotoLibrary]performChanges:^{
         PHAssetChangeRequest *changeRequest = [PHAssetChangeRequest changeRequestForAsset:lastImageAsset];
         changeRequest.contentEditingOutput = output;
       } completionHandler:^(BOOL success, NSError * _Nullable error) {
         NSLog(@"%@, %i", error, success);
       }];
  }];
```

I've also tried

```
CIImage *inputImage = [CIImage imageWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];
inputImage = [inputImage imageByApplyingOrientation:contentEditingInput.fullSizeImageOrientation];
```

Thanks for your time.

**UPDATE WITH SOLUTION**

This works:

```
 [lastImageAsset
      requestContentEditingInputWithOptions:options
                          completionHandler:^(PHContentEditingInput *contentEditingInput, NSDictionary *info) {

       NSURL *imageURL = contentEditingInput.fullSizeImageURL;

       CIImage *inputImage = [CIImage imageWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];
       inputImage = [inputImage imageByApplyingOrientation:contentEditingInput.fullSizeImageOrientation];

       EAGLContext *glContext = [[EAGLContext alloc]initWithAPI:kEAGLRenderingAPIOpenGLES2];
       CIContext *context = [CIContext contextWithEAGLContext:glContext];
       CGImageRef imageRef = [context createCGImage:inputImage fromRect:inputImage.extent];
       UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef scale:1.0 orientation:UIImageOrientationUp];

       NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0);


       PHContentEditingOutput *output = [[PHContentEditingOutput alloc]initWithContentEditingInput:contentEditingInput];
       PHAdjustmentData *adjustmentData = [[PHAdjustmentData alloc]initWithFormatIdentifier:@"Some Identifier" formatVersion:@"1.0" data:[@"Changed Something" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
       [output setAdjustmentData:adjustmentData];
       [imageData writeToURL:output.renderedContentURL atomically:YES];

       [[PHPhotoLibrary sharedPhotoLibrary]performChanges:^{
         PHAssetChangeRequest *changeRequest = [PHAssetChangeRequest changeRequestForAsset:lastImageAsset];
         changeRequest.contentEditingOutput = output;
       } completionHandler:^(BOOL success, NSError * _Nullable error) {
         NSLog(@"%@, %i", error, success);
       }];
  }];
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay finally found something that works:

```
CIImage *inputImage = [CIImage imageWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];
inputImage = [inputImage imageByApplyingOrientation:contentEditingInput.fullSizeImageOrientation];

EAGLContext *glContext = [[EAGLContext alloc]initWithAPI:kEAGLRenderingAPIOpenGLES2];
CIContext *context = [CIContext contextWithEAGLContext:glContext];
CGImageRef imageRef = [context createCGImage:inputImage fromRect:inputImage.extent];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef scale:1.0 orientation:UIImageOrientationUp];

NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0);
```

Now that imageData writes and maintains the orientation. Special thanks to https://github.com/vandadnp/iOS-8-Swift-Programming-Cookbook/blob/master/chapter-camera/Editing%20Images%20and%20Videos%20Right%20on%20the%20Device/Editing%20Images%20and%20Videos%20Right%20on%20the%20Device/ViewController.swift

Comment: congrats! :D .. please update your question with the complete solution for other people who may have the same issue in the future :)

Comment: Sure thing Marcio! And thanks for taking my message :)